# Jquery stop slideUp if user hovers over div

Tags: jquery, slideup

I am trying to stop a slideUp effect if the user is still hovering over the slideDown div. The slideDown div is "utility-nav1"

Any help or tips appreciated on my current code below:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$j(document).ready(function() {         
//show cart slide on hover
$j("#u1_cart").mouseenter(function() {
$j(this).addClass("open");
$j("#utility-nav1").slideDown();
$j("#slide-cart").load("cart_load.php", function() {
$j("#utility-nav1-loading").hide()
});
});                     
//hide cart slide on exit
$j("#u1_cart").mouseleave(function() {
$j("#utility-nav1").slideUp("slow", function() {
$j('#u1_cart').removeClass("open")
});
});
});
```

Comment: Kind of hard to figure out what you're trying to do without seeing some HTML.  Could you create a mockup in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML & CSS, I can't be 100% sure of the issue, but I think there are two likely places where you're running into trouble:

1. `.slideDown`, `.slideUp`, and `.slideToggle` require a `display:none` property to be given to the element either at the beginning or end of the animation. Therefore, if you try interrupting the animation, subsequent `.slide` calls will not work correctly. [Here's an example of this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/9SCLX/4/).
2. You may need to call `.stop()` on the element prior to calling the next animation. This will stop the previous one.

Based on the two points above, I'd advise you to forgo the `display:none` property on the element, and rather than calling a `.slide` method, simply animate the height.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/9SCLX/3/).

And the code:

```
$(function(){
    var mainDiv = $('.main');
    $('.btn').hover(function(){
        mainDiv.stop().animate({height:'200px'},1000);
    },function(){
        mainDiv.stop().animate({height:'0px'},1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I do have the display:none property on the div #utility-nav1, I know there is a double up in the JS code to hide #utility-nav1. So I should be able to use the slideUp and slideDown but I just need it to stop() if the user is still hovering over the sliding div.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. I'm advising against using the .slide methods...

Comment: This acheives the same result as slideUp or slideDown but I am trying to prevent slideUp if the user is hovering over the div mainDiv

Comment: You can delete the console.log lines. Those were just for debugging on my part. And they would only throw an error if you are using a browser without a console... which you should never be doing when developing.

Answer (score 0):

#### I would suggest using [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) which does most of the hard work for you.

This uses the approach that Jacob Nielson recommends as it prevents users opening the cart by accident if they are moving their cursor past it.

This is untested but should work

```
$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j("#utility-nav1").hide(); 

    //show cart slide on hover
    function openCart() {
        $j(this).addClass("open");
        $j("#utility-nav1").slideDown();
        $j("#slide-cart").load("cart_load.php", function() {
            $j("#utility-nav1-loading").hide();
        });
    }       

    //hide cart slide on exit
    function closeCart() {
        $j("#utility-nav1").slideUp("slow", function() {
            $j('#u1_cart').removeClass("open")
        });
    }

    var config = {    
        over: openCart, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
        timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
        out: closeCart // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
    };


    // Call hoverIntent with your selector
    $j("#u1_cart").hoverIntent( config )


});
```

EDIT:
Ok based on your markup, this is the best I can do without changing lots of things.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // On hover of your link
  $("#hover").mouseenter(function(){

      // If not then perform the slideDown() animation
      $("#utility-nav1").stop(true,true).slideDown( function(){

        // When the aimation is complete, add the open class to your link
        $("#hover").addClass("open");

      });

  });



  $("#utility-nav1, #hover").mouseleave( function(){

    $("#utility-nav1").stop(true,true).delay(500).slideUp( function(){

      $("#hover").removeClass("open");

    });

  });

  $("#utility-nav1").mouseenter(function(){

    $("#utility-nav1").stop(true,true).slideDown();

  });



});

// close document.ready
```

[Here is a link to the JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ujiper/32/)

Comment: Hello, this works but what I am trying to achieve is for the cart to remain open or slideDown if the user is hovering over the div utility-nav1? This only slides the cart div down for X amount of time and then slideUp?

Comment: So I'm assuming that `#utility-nav1` isn't contained within `#u1_cart`?
Judging by the fact that we are sliding down `#utility-nav1` I would imagine that it should be:

`<div id="#u1_cart">
    <div id="#utility-nav1">
        Cart Stuff
    </div>
</div>`

If this is not possible or not desired then you may want to try calling `$j("#u1_cart, #utility-nav1").hoverIntent( config );`

This will require changes to the function `openCart();` to change `$j(this).addClass("open");` to `$j(#u1_cart).addClass("open");` as `$(this)` will be different depending on which element you are hovering over.

Comment: Hi Craig, That was a great I idea but unfortunately it does not stop() if the user hovers over #utility-nav1 it still sildes up after 5000. I have update the code above with your new suggestion.

Comment: It may be as simple as adding `$j("#utility-nav1").hover( function(){ $(this).stop(true,true).show(); }, function(){$(this).stop(true,true).delay(5000).slideUp();});`so that whenever your mouse is over `$j("#utility-nav1")` it is showing.

You may have to play about with `.animate()`

I should be able to solve this if you put your markup into http://jsbin.com so I know the context.

Comment: Hello Craig try here http://jsbin.com/ujiper/24/edit#javascript,html,live its very buggie, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not...